# Добавить элементы в словарь через input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу разобраться как добавить новые ключи в словарь

Необходимо запрашивать данные у пользователя, после чего дополнять словарь, но не знаю как добавить новые элекменты словаря

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    user = dict()
    name = input("Введите имя: ")
    age = input("Введите возраст ")
    user[name] = age
    username = dict(user)
    print(user)
    i = i + 1
print("всё")
```

как можно сохранить ранее введённые данные, чтобы после вывести список и 5 ключей с сохранёными в нём данными

Comment: объявить словарь перед while и выводить его после после while?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
username = dict()

while True:
    name = input("Введите имя (или Enter - выход): ")
    if not name:
        break
    age = input("Введите возраст: ")
   
    # Добавить в словарь если пользователя с именем `name` ранее не было.
    # Если вы хотите не только добавлять, но и изменять age у уже существующих `name`,
    # удалите две строки ниже.
    isName = username.get(name, None)
    if isName is None:
        username[name] = age    

print(username)
```